# jQuery Flip, why do i need to declare variable?

Tags: jquery, flip

I'm trying to use this flip plugin: http://lab.smashup.it/flip/ but I can't get it to work as wanted.

This works:

```
<div class="flip" id="flipbox2" onclick="doFlip();">
    Flip me!
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var $flipbox = $('#flipbox2');
        function doFlip() {
            $flipbox.flip({
                direction: 'lr',
                bgColor: '#FFFFF',
                color: '#000000',
                speed: 500,
                content: "Goodbye World!"
            });
        };
</script>
```

But when I remove the var $flipbox = $('#flipbox2'); declaration and use $('#flipbox2') in the function doFlip() instead it doesn't work.

To be clear, this does NOT work:

```
<div class="flip" id="flipbox2" onclick="doFlip();">
    Flip me!
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function doFlip() {
            $('#flipbox2').flip({
                direction: 'lr',
                bgColor: '#FFFFF',
                color: '#000000',
                speed: 500,
                content: "Goodbye World!"
            });
        };
</script>
```

Why is this not working? Any ideas?

Comment: `$(document).on('ready', function() { Any stuff requiring DOM elements to exist });`

Comment: @Virus721 - $(document).on('ready', function () {
                    function doFlip() {
                        alert('click');
                    }
                }); this doesn't fire.

Comment: @Virus721 Not relevant in this case.

Comment: @Juhana It is. Querying an element which isn't loaded yet will return an empty collection, even if there is another mistake in the code.

Comment: @Virus712 the code is invoked on click. The user can't click on the element before it exists.

Comment: When I try your code in my browser, both forms work.  Tested with Safari on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out both forms of the code actually works. Seems as one of my asp controls is messing up the page in some way.